# codeigniter cart: display cart for multiple store

Tags: codeigniter, cart

The idea is that I'm going to build a website that process purchases to some different stores registered in my website using CodeIgniter. The challenge is coming when I want to display the content of cart only the item from the shop currently viewed by the buyer. I came across to using the cart's options index for passing the store id so that I can use it to identify from which store the item from.

But I'm not sure how to do it because I don't know how to select certain cart content based on an identifier like store id. Can anyone give an idea about it? Thank you at advance.

Comment: Are these stores inside your application or are you talking about processing purchases via another online storefront?

Comment: yes, the stores are inside my application. I mean, they made an account in my website and they can manage their own products.

Comment: Okay then it's a matter of managing your tables correctly then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could add the store_id to the item options.

Then, when looping through your cart contents with foreach, the first line of your loop checks the options and if the store_id doesn't match - skip the rest of the loop code (with continue;).

Alternatively you could extend the cart class and override the contents() method to do this for you to make your view code a little cleaner.

Comment: thank you for your idea, it sounds good. But I just don't know how to do the `foreach` loop you mean. Can you show me the `foreach` code a bit? :)

Comment: Your question states you don't know how to filter by store id when displaying the cart.  That implies you know how to display the cart in the first place... anyhow, it looks like:


`foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item) {`
`... do your option checking here`
`}`

You can see a full description [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html)

Comment: Hey, it works like a charm!!! But now I have a new problem. The total amount of the cart using `$this->cart->total()` is still the total amount of all items in the cart, while I need to get the amount of cart from each store. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, that's correct - you'll have to either calculate the total on the fly (just sum the subtotal of each item as you iterate through your view) or extend the cart class (there's many stackoverflow questions about this) and then add your own function... maybe like `function total_by_store($store_id)` that takes the store ID, iterates through like you would in your view and returns the total that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a matter of managing your tables correctly.

**Very basic table outline**.

- Store table with store specific information and a unique ID, each store has their own row.
- Products table with product specific information.
- User table
- Inventory table, quantity, productID, storeID
- Cart table stores user and inventory id's (and anything else you need)

Then when you do your cart query the individual products are linked to an individual store via the inventory table.

You'll probably have to think it through in a little more detail for handling individual products, prices etc from multiple stores but that should get you started down the right path. This is a very whittled down version of our online application. We actually have listing tables too where the pricing goes.

Comment: I have already storeID, productID and so in my inventory table but my problem is how to display only product from (for example) John's store in the cart when the visitor is viewing John's store. The products from other store shouldn't show up. Is there something I can do with `$this->cart->contents()` function to do it?

Comment: Oh, you're using CI's built in cart thing? Sorry zero experience with that I just write my own ecommerce stuff. For the select it's simple SELECT * WHERE storeId = $johns_id

Comment: Yes, at the moment I try to use CI cart function to store data of products selected by buyer. I will not store them on a table in database before the buyer finished his checkout. Thank u anyway @Rick